# Password field is not working as expected in Safari browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iphone, html, safari, mobile-safari

I have login form with email company name and password and its working on all browsers except Safari. Please find below the code for password field.

```
    <div class="formparts">
      <label for="user_raw_password">
        <%= t('activemodel.users.sign_in.password') %>
        <span class="required"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="textField">
        <%=
          text_field_tag 'user[raw_password]',
          '',
          id: 'user_raw_password',
          class: 'form-control secondary_password',
          placeholder: '',
          type: 'password',
          autofocus: true,
          data: {
            parsley_required: true
          }
        %>
        <input data-parsley-required type="hidden" name="user[password]" id="user_password" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user[public_key_version]" id="user_public_key_version" />
        <%= fancy_bottom_for_input %>
      </div>
      <a class="showPassword"><%= t('activemodel.users.sign_in.show_password') %></a>
    </div>
```

Problem is that when I type password in Safari it is  not getting displayed as I am just getting blank spaces and after sometime it is rendering bullets.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the login process in the same window then the problem occurs because Safari is not able to handle the login session in the same window.
Try to create login session in another window by using:
Window.open or by condition : if has_safari? .

Comment: Its actually a 2 steps process, in step 1 it gets the email and company id in step 2 it asks for password.